# How to do a JSON request in CoffeeScript without jQuery

Tags: json, node.js, coffeescript

jQuery is not usable as I'm looking at a node-js based server application here.

**EDIT** it doesn actually look like a simple question. Googling however did not help as I way trying to use `http` or `request` against localhost. Unfortunately there seems to be an issues in node that tries to route localhost through our proxy which fails .

Comment: node.js has [documentation](http://nodejs.org/documentation/api/) (which took less than a minute to find). Have you read it? Or at least scanned it for something that might be useful?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the node http module.

```
http = require 'http'

var options = 
  host: 'http://www.test.com',
  path: '/test.json'

callback = (response) ->
  # do stuff

http.request(options, callback).end();
```